# How to write a huge log in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, logging, large-data

I need to log a huge number of events when running a .js file, and so far I've tried to use `console.log(data)` to record all the data, as then I can save from the browser log (I'm using Chrome).
However, I've run into the problem that there are so many log messages, the browser only holds the tail ones, whereas I need all of them.

I was wondering if I could either make Google Chrome store more log messages, or store the log as a file on the computer? I need to be able to append as I do not know when the logs will stop, and I would prefer not to have to send data through a server to have a client receive and store the log locally.

Comment: Have you tried with local storage? http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Store them in a string instead of logging. Then print them: `document.body.innerHTML = '<plaintext>'+log_messages`.

Comment: @salih0vicX I thought that Chrome only stored 5MB of local storage? If so, this probably won't do; I'm storing a large amount of data.

Comment: @Boldewyn I don't know when I will need to stop logging... can I use document.body.innerHTML += "string"?

Comment: can you save it as a file? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32295448/1119279

Comment: @TheAbelo2 - How are you keeping track of the logs in your javascript code? Are you saving them to an array? Is it a circular array? Is that why you are only retaining the tail of the logs?

Comment: I am using Console.log() and writing one message at a time, as a function is repeatedly called. I am only retaining the tail of the logs because there are so many log messages Google Chrome gets rid of the start ones.

Comment: Say that it would be possible, wouldn't that be a great way to annoy people by writing large amounts of data to their drives, potentially even filling up the drives completely?

Comment: @robertklep I don't need an automatic download, or even a download at all. I just need a way to log a large amount of data and Google Chrome doesn't keep enough log data for me to do so.

Comment: @TheAbelo2 what I'm trying to say is that, most likely, Chrome won't allow you to do that, because it would be a good vector for malicious intent.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I used `File` and `Blob` to make a download link to the file that was saved when the log stopped, providing a download link:

```
function fileOut(data) {
    properties = {type: 'plain/text'};
    try {
      file = new File(data, "file.txt", properties);
    } catch (e) {
      file = new Blob(data, properties);
    }
    url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    document.getElementById('gb-log').href = url; // Create download link
}
```